# How to read from an I2C pressure sensor on Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

For my current project I've attached a MEAS M32JM pressure & temperature sensor to my Pi, but I've been unable to read the sensor values using its I2C protocol.

Here is the sensor's datasheet:
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/8/ENG_DS_M3200_A19-1958281.pdf

**NOTE: check out the C example code at the end of the datasheet**

The datasheet mentions:

> The I2C address consists of a 7-digit binary value. The factory
> setting for the I2C slave address is 0x28. The address is always
> followed by a write bit (0) or read bit (1). The default hexadecimal
> I2C header for read access to the sensor is therefore 0x51.

This is what I tried:

```
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x28
read_header = 0x51

bus.write_byte_data(address, read_header, 0x01)  # Start reading: 0 = WRITE, 1 = READ

time.sleep(0.7)

for i in range(8):
    print(bus.read_byte_data(address, i))
```

However, all the prints return **0**.

The datasheet also mentions that after sending the read bit, we have to wait for an **acknowledge** bit, but how would I receive and process that bit?

Never worked with I2C or bitwise operations before, so any help with how I can read data from this sensor would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it using `pigpio` instead of `smbus`.

I installed it on the Pi using:

```
apt install pigpio
apt-get install python-pigpio python3-pigpio
```

Then I used the following Python script to read the sensor data:

```
import pigpio

SENSOR_ADDRESS = 0x28  # 7 bit address 0101000-, check datasheet or run `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`
BUS = 1

pi = pigpio.pi()

handle = pi.i2c_open(BUS, SENSOR_ADDRESS)

# Attempt to write to the sensor, catch exceptions
try:
  pi.i2c_write_quick(handle, 1)  # Send READ_MR command to start measurement and DSP calculation cycle
except:
  print("Error writing to the sensor, perhaps none is connected to bus %s" % bus, file=sys.stderr)
  pi.stop()
  return None

time.sleep(2 / 1000)  # Give the sensor some time

count, data = pi.i2c_read_device(handle, 4)  # Send READ_DF4 command, to fetch 2 pressure bytes & 2 temperature bytes

pi.i2c_close(handle)
pi.stop()

print("count = ", count)
print("data = ", data)
```

[Click here to see the full script](https://github.com/nickkraakman/tesla-turbine-telemetry/blob/master/meas.py).